# How to create a list of parent objects where each parent can have a list of child objects?

Tags: vb.net, class, nested

In VB.NET 2010, How would one go about creating a list of Parent classes where each Parent has it's own list of Child classes. Where the list of child classes could be as few as 1 child or as many as a few hundred child objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim ChildList as generic.list(of object)
Dim ParentList as generic.list(of ChildList)
```

You can do it like above

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a LinkedList object:

LinkedList Outer;

where ParentType is a class that has another LinkedList object of it own:

```
Public Class ParentType

    Private myChildren As LinkedList<ChildType>
```

ChildType in above could even be replaced with "ParentType," if it's a list of the exact same kind of object.

For more detail on LinkedList:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ky9a64s.aspx