# Getting a property from the instantiator class

Tags: vb.net, class, inheritance

Not an experienced programmer, so probably not a hard question.

Developing a small application in VB.net in WPF.
I made 3 classes, EngineeringObject<==Inherits==PartOfInstallation<==Inherits==SensorActor

In the class SensorActor I'm trying to get a property of PartOfInstallation with the function MyBase.Name. But this goes directly to EngineeringObject. How do I solve this?

```
Public Class EngineeringObject
''Private declarations, alleen objecten die erven kunnen hieraan, of dmv van getters en setters
'Name of part
Private sName As String = "Naam"

'81346 Id's
Private sSystemId As String = "Functie" 'VentilationSystem, Pumpsystem
Private sLocationId As String = "Locatie" 'Room 0.0
Private sObjectId As String = "Object" 'Fan, Pump

'General
Private sPartNumber As String
Private sLinkToDatasheet As String

'Property's
Public Property Name() As String
    Get
        Return sName
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        sName = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property SystemId() As String
    Get
        Return sSystemId
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        sSystemId = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property PartNumber() As String
    Get
        Return sPartNumber
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        sPartNumber = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property LinkToDatasheet() As String
    Get
        Return sLinkToDatasheet
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        sLinkToDatasheet = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Sub New()

End Sub

End Class

Public Class PartOfInstallation
Inherits EngineeringObject

'src: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21308881/parent-creating-child-object
'src: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16244548/how-to-create-a-list-of-parent-objects-where-each-parent-can-have-a-list-of-chil
Private lSensorActor As New List(Of SensorActor)

Public Function GetSensorActor()
    Return Me.lSensorActor
End Function

Public Sub CreateSensorActor()
    lSensorActor.Add(New SensorActor)
End Sub

End Class

Public Class SensorActor
Inherits PartOfInstallation
Dim sMyPartOfInstallation As String

Public Property MyPartOfInstallation As String
    Get
        Return sMyPartOfInstallation
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        sMyPartOfInstallation = MyBase.Name

    End Set
End Property

End Class
```

Comment: The only `Name` property that `PartOfInstallation` has is the one it inherits from `EngineeringObject`. What other `Name` property are you expecting to be returned?

Comment: The problem I have is that it takes "Naam" as value of EngineeringObject instead of the value I fill in at the PartOfInstallation.

Comment: When I'm running the program, and creating multiple objects of the class PartOfInstallation. With all a different name, then when I instantiate a SensorActor on a specific PartOfInstallation, I would expect it to take that name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, based on your comments, you want every `SensorActor` instantiated within a `PartOfInstallation` instance to get the same name as that instance.

If so, then just add a second constructor to your `SensorActor` class allowing you to pass a name for it as well:

```
Public Class SensorActor
    Inherits PartOfInstallation

    ...your code...

    Public Sub New() 'Empty constructor, for if/when you don't want to set the name immediately.
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal Name As String)
        Me.Name = Name
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now in your `PartOfInstallation` class you can do:

```
Public Sub CreateSensorActor()
    lSensorActor.Add(New SensorActor(Me.Name)) 'Here, "Me" refers to the current PartOfInstallation instance.
End Sub
```

**Alternatively** you can make the `SensorActor` constructor take a `PartOfInstallation` instance instead, allowing you to copy any properties you like:

```
Public Class SensorActor
    Inherits PartOfInstallation

    ...your code...

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal BasedOnPOI As PartOfInstallation)
        Me.Name = BasedOnPOI.Name
    End Sub
End Class
```

Thus making the code in the `PartOfInstallation` class:

```
Public Sub CreateSensorActor()
    lSensorActor.Add(New SensorActor(Me))
End Sub
```

**Read more about constructors:** [**Object Lifetime: How Objects Are Created and Destroyed (Visual Basic) | Microsoft Docs**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/objects-and-classes/object-lifetime-how-objects-are-created-and-destroyed#using-constructors-and-destructors)

Comment: Thanks alot! I have the result I want now. When I fill in (in a datagrid) that the name of PartOfInstallation equals "=B" and I then try to fill in the name of the SensorActor as "F5". It corrects the name to "=B.F5"

Answer (score 0):

The result below, if there's room for improvement... always welcome.

SensorActor

```
Public Class SensorActor
Inherits PartOfInstallation
Dim sTemp As String



Public Overloads Property SystemId() As String
    Get
        Return Me.sSystemId
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        Me.sSystemId = sTemp + "." + value
    End Set
End Property

Public Sub New(ByVal BasedOnPOI As PartOfInstallation)
    sTemp = BasedOnPOI.SystemId
End Sub



End Class
```

PartOfInstallation

```
Public Class PartOfInstallation
Inherits EngineeringObject

'src: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21308881/parent-creating-child-object
'src: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16244548/how-to-create-a-list-of-parent-objects-where-each-parent-can-have-a-list-of-chil
Private lSensorActor As New List(Of SensorActor)


Public Function GetSensorActor()
    Return Me.lSensorActor
End Function



Public Sub CreateSensorActor()
    lSensorActor.Add(New SensorActor(Me))
End Sub

End Class
```

EngineeringObject

```
Public Class EngineeringObject
''Private declarations, alleen objecten die erven kunnen hieraan, of dmv van getters en setters
'Name of part
Private sName As String = "Naam"

'81346 Id's
Friend sSystemId As String = "Functie" 'VentilationSystem, Pumpsystem
Private sLocationId As String = "Locatie" 'Room 0.0
Private sObjectId As String = "Object" 'Fan, Pump

'General
Private sPartNumber As String
Private sLinkToDatasheet As String

'Property's
Public Property Name() As String
    Get
        Return sName
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        sName = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property SystemId() As String
    Get
        Return sSystemId
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        sSystemId = "=" + value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property PartNumber() As String
    Get
        Return sPartNumber
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        sPartNumber = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property LinkToDatasheet() As String
    Get
        Return sLinkToDatasheet
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        sLinkToDatasheet = value
    End Set
End Property





Public Sub New()

End Sub

End Class
```